# Change INT Default value of mysql(phpmyadmin) in mysql version 5.7.2

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Currently, I have the MySQL 5.6 version. In this version `INT` type column will take 0 automatically even by default value is none.

> Column = question_status, Type= INT, Default= None

Old query : `INSERT INTO  tbl_question (question_status)  VALUES ('');`

Above Query will Run Perfectly on my older version.

Now, I have imported the database into a newer version of MySQL 5.7.2

New query : `INSERT INTO  tbl_question (question_status)  VALUES ('');`

Above query is same but it says I have to change the default value of column because column datatype is `INT`.

if I'll change the default value manually to 0 in the newer version. It will run perfectly.

The problem is I have around 100 tables in a database and many `INT` Type columns so I cant change default value of every column one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all columns having an INT type with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '<YOUR_DB>' data_type = 'INT'
```

Then it will be easy to write a simple script for a mass alter.

Comment: like i said i have so many columns and it's still loading select query after 6 mins.
is there any way to configure mysql default value ?

Comment: Try setting innodb_stats_on_metadata=0 . It should make queries to information_schema work faster.

Comment: it is showing all the database fields. I want the select database.

Comment: Then add table_schema = 'YOUR_DB' to the WHERE part of the query.